# how to retrieve the employee who got maximum bonus?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to display the employee detail who has got the maximum bonus(one with employee details and another table with bonus details). Here I have created a 'performance bonus' column to sum up the multiple bonuses. How to retrieve the employee from that column?

```
select e.Employee_id,
       e.First_name,
       e.Department,
       e.Salary,
       coalesce((select sum(b.Bonus_Amount) 
    as Bonus-- Let's sum up all Employee's the bonuses
from Employee_Bonus_Table b
where b.Employee_ref_id = e.Employee_Id), 0) [Performance_bonus]
    from Employee_Table e
```

Comment: Instead `JOIN` and use a `TOP(1)`?

Comment: i have tried on top of that like this.=>select top 1 * (the above code) where performance_ bonus=(select max(performance_bonus) from b;

Comment: Note I said use a `JOIN` too...

Comment: it says incorrect syntax near ';'

Comment: inner join? pl clear me little more

Comment: ok I will try Join.

Comment: Take your first comment, remove the WHERE clause but keep TOP 1. Then Add an appropriate ORDER BY clause. Learn to look up syntax in the documentation and find similar discussions by searching the internet.

Comment: ```                                                                                                                            
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employee_Table
JOIN Employee_Bonus_Table
ON Employee_id=Employee_Bonus_Table.Employee_ref_id
where Bonus_Amount= (select max(Bonus_Amount) from Employee_Bonus_Table);
```

Comment: I got employee details with bonus but only one bonus amount is reflecting and not added one more bonus to the same employee. how to add here?

Comment: remove where clause and add order by clause..ok i will try that

Comment: You should always include sample data and desired results for clarity.

Comment: @Dale K thank you for your inputs and will do it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the task correctly, then the bonuses can be repeated, is that right?
then we must first sum up all the bonuses by employee, then sort from largest to smallest and get the first one from the list

```sql
--- for examples:
with Employee_Bonus_Table as(
    select Bonus_Amount = 1 ,Employee_ref_id = 1
    union select Bonus_Amount = 1000 ,Employee_ref_id = 2
    union select Bonus_Amount = 2000 ,Employee_ref_id = 2


),Employee_Table as (
    select Employee_id=1
       ,First_name='First_name'
       ,Department= 'Department'
       ,Salary = 1000

    UNION select Employee_id=2
       ,First_name='First_name2'
       ,Department= 'Department2'
       ,Salary = 2000
)
--reslut query:
select top 1
       e.Employee_id,
       e.First_name,
       e.Department,
       e.Salary,
       b.sumBonus_Amount
  from Employee_Table e
        join (select sumBonus_Amount = sum(Bonus_Amount), Employee_ref_id 
            from  Employee_Bonus_Table
            group by Employee_ref_id
            ) b on b.Employee_ref_id = e.Employee_Id
order by b.sumBonus_Amount desc
```

Comment: exactly...what I expected as output...thanks in tons..